# Vector Drawable not Overriding

Tags: android, compatibility, android-vectordrawable

I have the following directory structure:

```
drawable/ic_logo.xml
drawable-v24/ic_logo.xml
```

The issue I am experiencing is that the `v24` version of `ic_logo` is not overriding the "default" drawable folder version and the application displays the default on all API versions.

The reason I have to use a `v24` version is because of the vector containing a gradient which needs `startX`, `startY` etc. which are not available until API 24.

My `minSdkVersion` is 21, and I'm calling the vector from a `AppCompatImageView` like so:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Strangely, the logo is displayed correctly for API < 23 and API 24 and above when using the Android Studio previewer, but not on any emulator or live device.

Comment: simply use `startX`, and `startY` - it will be ignored on <24 devices

Comment: Hi @David you can use different name SVG icon for v24 and please setDrawable programmatically. As far I know vector drawable are generated to PNG files at compile time and that source SVG asset is taken from drawable resource directory only.
This might be your case.

Comment: @PankajKantPatel, right I will try that, but it seems counter intuitive as the above works for image assets but not for vectors? Why is this? (Seems like a bug)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, I'm under brand guidelines and the logo falls within these so if it is not replicated I have to use a "fallback" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@PankajKantPatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2298357/pankaj-kant-patel), I have implemented a "workaround" for this.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    logo.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo, null));
}else{
    logo.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo_24, null));
}
```

I still feel this is a bug as it should follow the same logic as an image asset, I will log a bug with Google for this.